# How does a subclass' call to its superclass' constructor assign values to the fields it inherits from the superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, super

I've been trying to understand this for a while and just can't seem to wrap my head around it.
This is what I think I know so far.

- If class A extends class B, it must, either implicitly, or explicitly, make a call to its parent   class' constructor in its own constructor.
- This is done so that the inheritance relationship can actually work or exist: the subclass cannot extend the superclass if the superclass' fields and methods aren't initialized via the call to the super constructor.
  --When the subclass' constructor is called, the superclass' constructor must be run first because of the above point.
  Are the above points more or less right?

Now this is what I'm especially trying to understand. Say we have the following situation:

```
public class A {
    private String name;

    public A(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    
    public B(String name) {
        super(name);
    }    
}
```

If we had B b = new B("Something"), then the first thing done by B's constructor would be to make the call super("Something").

I'm just confused how this translates into B's name field now being "something". Because the call to super goes into A's constructor, and has this.name = name. I keep thinking that now A's name field is "Something". How does this.name = name; in A's constructor (super()) result in B's name field being "Something"? And when in this process did B inherit this name field from A? (Was it the precise moment it called super()?)
Sorry if this question became a bit lengthy, greatly appreciate any help!

I've tried to understand why the result I'm observing is happening and haven't been able to pinpoint a precise explanation why. I have searched on stack overflow and while the threads were very helpful in understanding more about inheritance and super(), I couldn't find exactly a question that was similar to mine.

Comment: `B` doesn't have a separate `name` field from `A`.  There's only one `name` field declared in your code.  The best way to think of this is that a `B` instance is a special kind of `A` instance that has (usually) some extra functionality, in addition to all the methods and fields that it gets by virtue of being an `A` instance.

Comment: I see what you're saying, that's definitely a more helpful way of thinking about it, thank you! So would it be correct to think of it like this then? The call to super initializes the members of the superclass so that the subclass inherits them; then whatever setting of those fields' values the superclass' constructor does is effectively setting the value of the fields the subclass' now has? I think this is just an unnecessarily complicated way of rephrasing it and that I'm just overthinking it. Greatly appreciate your help again!

Comment: a class is a "type" , an int , float , long , char are all primitive types. Classes themselves are "complex types".  A is a type B is a type and when two or more complex types are fused / welded together they are known generally as a polymorphic type. Polymorphism is the ability of an object to be more than one type. When B extends A (provided A is not declared final) then B is both A and B and in that particular "instance" A is both A and B too. String is a complex type, Integer , Float Long are classes and complex type, and all "final" classes that do not allow extending from.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think that inheritance somehow "happens" at runtime. It does not. Inheritance is a description of the class you are declaring, namely you are saying that the class *also* has some of the members of whatever superclass you specified has, and that an instance of your class can be used  as an instance of the superclass, among other things.

From [JLS 8.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2):

> The members of a class are all of the following:
>
> - Members inherited from its direct superclass type (§8.1.4), except in the class Object, which has no direct superclass type
> - Members inherited from any direct superinterface types (§8.1.5)
> - Members declared in the body of the class (§8.1.7)
>
> Members of a class that are declared private are not inherited by subclasses of that class.
>
> Only members of a class that are declared protected or public are inherited by subclasses declared in a package other than the one in which the class is declared.

Inheritance is not something that can be "executed" at runtime. Asking *when* inheritance happens is like asking *when* does class `A` begin to have the field `name` - it has the field `name` the moment you wrote `private String name;`.

In fact, Your `B` class doesn't even inherit `name` as one of its members, since both the quote above and [JLS 8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3) says that private fields are not inherited.

According to [JLS 15.11.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.1), this is what the field access `this.name` in `A`'s constructor means.

> [...] then the result is a variable, namely the named member field in type `T` found in the object referenced by the value of the `Primary`.

For context, `T` is `A`, `Primary` is the expression `this`. `this` refers to an object, which is the instance of `B` that is currently being created.

So what fields does the object of `B` referred to by `this` has? See [JLS 15.9.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4) for what happens when creating an instance,

> The new object contains new instances of all the fields declared in the specified class and all its superclasses. As each new field instance is created, it is initialized to its default value (§4.12.5).

In other words, `this.name` means the `name` field declared in `A`, and that is what you are setting. There is only one field, `name`, in an instance of `B`, whether or not `name` is inherited.

So regarding "I'm just confused how this translates into `B`'s `name` field now being `"something"`", there is no such thing as "`B`'s `name` field". You are setting `A`'s `name` field, which an object of `B` has.

Think about what happens when you call some method of `A` on an instance of `B`, that happens to depend on `name`. If `A`'s constructor was not called to initialise `name`, the method might not work correctly. Of course, in a simple case like in your code, this probably is less likely to happen, so imagine that `A`'s constructor actually does complicated initialisation logic, making sure e.g. invariants are satisfied, so that its methods can safely assume things.

This is why you are required to call `super(...)` - to ensure that the subclass is in a "properly initialised" state, **as far as the superclass is concerned**, so that methods in the superclass can work properly. Java forces you to do this as the first thing you do in a subclass' constructor.

Comment: What do you mean by _"... just because a class has a field as one of its members, doesn't mean that an instance of that class will also have it ..."_ ?  I find that a very strange assertion.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I might have overcomplicated this by quoting from the spec, but that is the most authoritative source for how Java should behave.

Comment: I don't think the JLS does actually contain the sentence of yours that I quoted.  I don't believe there's any scenario in which a non-static field is declared in a class, but an instance of that class doesn't have that field.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by _"... an instance of a class will only have the fields that are declared in its class and its superclasses, but not the inherited fields ..."_ in your answer, and _"...  inherited fields are not in the instance, only declared ones in the class and its superclasses ..."_ in your comment.  What could the inherited fields possibly be, other than fields declared in the class or its superclasses?  I just can't get my head around what you're trying to say - which suggests to me that the OP might also have difficulty understanding this answer.

Comment: Let me try again. Inheritance is a description of a class. It is saying that the class will have some inherited members. According to 15.11.1, the meaning of a field access however, depends on what fields are in the instance (aka “object” as per 15.11.1). There is no reason to assume anything about what fields an instance of of `B` will have. We only know what fields the classes `A` and `B` has, from their declarations and their inheritance relationship. The quote from 15.9.4 explains the relationship between fields in an object and the field members of a class.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, this code does not call super but the B instance has all the A instance field values

```
public class A {

   private String name;

   public A() {
      this.name = "Some A";
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "A{" +
              "name='" + name + '\'' +
              '}';
   }

}


public class B extends A {

   public B(){
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return super.toString();
   }
}

public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      B b = new B();
      System.out.println(b);
   }
}
```

Result

```
A{name='Some A'}
```

Comment: Yes I think your comment has explain it before

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I think it's correct now